# OSX application loses permissions to read a directory after app re-start

Tags: objective-c, macos, entitlements

My OSX application is intended to monitor a folder on the computer which the user has selected. Very simply, I have a function which scans the directory:

```
- (NSError*)scan:(NSString*)dir {
  NSError *err = nil;
  NSArray *filenames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dir error:&err];
  for(NSString* fn in filenames) {
    NSString *fp = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fn];
    BOOL isDir;
    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fp isDirectory:&isDir];
    if(exists && isDir) {
      [self scan:fp];
    }
    else {
      [self handleFile:fp];
    }
  }
  NSLog(@"Scanning %@: %@",dir,err);
  return err;
}
```

When I first start the application, I present a UI to select the folder and then immediately scan it. The operation works great (no errors).

When I restart the application, I attempt to scan the directory again, but this time the `NSLog` spits out an error:

```
Scanning /Users/zane/Dropbox/Gifs: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Gifs” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo=0x608000476d40 {NSFilePath=/Users/zane/Dropbox/Gifs, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
), NSUnderlyingError=0x60800005d3d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -5000.)"}
```

Note that the path has not changed.

I suspect that the problem has to do with `.entitlements`. Here's what I've got:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "When I restart the application, I attempt to scan the directory again"?  You mean, you've tried to scan the exact same folder after saving and reading the last folder path?

Comment: I mean I close the app, start it up, and run the function again (with the same path for the `dir` pameter).

Comment: I'll ask again.  Just say yes or no.  Are you reading the same directory with the string path you've saved and then loaded?  Or are you just manually selecting the same directory for the 2nd round?  If it's the first case, then you have a bookmark issue.

Comment: Yes; the former. I present the UI to select the folder only on the first start, and not on the second. Where can I find information on how to fix said "bookmark issue?" That's a pretty tough-to-google term ;)

Comment: I'll check.  5 minutes...

Comment: Start Xcode, Command-Shift-0 to display help, enter "bookmark". It's a whole big lot of essential functionality that you need to actually _learn_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use the same file or folder the user already selected, then you need to save the path as a security-scoped bookmark when the user selects that path.  Read its bookmark data when the user restarts the application in order to use the saved path.  There's a description of security-scoped bookmark at the middle of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).  Use the **URLByResolvingBookmarkData** method of NSURL to return a security-scoped bookmark.  Use the **bookmarkDataWithOptions** method or equivalent of NSURL to resume the security-scoped bookmark.